# How To Click Particular WebElement in Appium

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcKGS.png)

Click On particular WebElement on Android using Selenium and Appium, after several trials, I created the screenshot to seek help here.

im getting Error NOSuch Element Exception

Comment: please provide some code samples

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
im getting This Error Please Help Me How To solve Ths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use android's uiautomatorviewer or appium Inspector to check the properties of the element. After knowing the properties of elements such as resource-id,cont-desc, xpath, classname etc You can click on that element.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("your resource id)).click();
//or
driver.findElement(By.xpath("......")).click();
```

please read: [How to use uiautomatorviewer and appium inspector?](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-inspector/)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible im getting This Error Please Help Me How To solve Ths

Comment: Did you started your appium server?

Comment: yaa i started Appium Server

Comment: Did you initialize your Appium driver and Desired Capbility correctly?

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi 5A");
   capabilities.setCapability("udid", "a20f9b347d94");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.2");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,

Comment: previously  it is working i uninstalled Appium and installed latest version

Comment: which appium version are you using currently? is it 1.8.1?

Comment: open your appium desktop app. Go to "**Advance**" tab. Add server address to "127.0.0.1", Server port to "4723", check (tick) "**Allow Session Override**". Start the server.  Use **driver=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(
                "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);** . Run the program

Comment: Did this actually work?  It's marked as the accepted answer, but this is the suggested fix elsewhere for the same problem and it hasn't worked for any of the other similar scenarios I've seen reported, including mine.  I launch the server through the java client instead of the desktop version, and I've tried setting the capabilities "--session-override" to true, made no difference.

Comment: I was getting the "impossible to create session" error mentioned in the OP's comment but I managed to get past it on my own.  After viewing the logs, I discovered that the UDID (or whatever) I was passing was incorrect.  I made the mistake of thinking it wanted the serial number.  Only through trial-and-error did I discover it wanted the results of adb devices command.  It's not a required capability setting, but if you set it incorrectly, you get that particular error message.  Thanks anyway.